# Distinct 12 month rolling count of unique customers

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, rolling-computation

I have a database of unique customers (CUST_ID), dates (MONTH_ID) and brands (ABC, XYZ) and I want to get a distinct count of each individual customer over a 12 month period for each brand. So, as an example, if a customer transacted three times with one brand over a 12 month period say in Jan21, Feb21 and Mar21 and I run a 12 month rolling report in Mar21 for that brand I would like this customer to show up **once** (not three times). Similarly, if they transacted in 10 of the 12 months again I would only want to count them once.

Ultimately, I need to assign a population weight to this customer over the 12 month period and we can't have them being counted three times in 12 months as it will throw off the customer penetration metric.

I would also like a **monthly** column in my data output like the below.

Essentially it is that last column I want to populate, but I keep getting a distinct count by month because I have the monthly column included rather than a count over a 12 month period.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: *I would like this customer to show up once (not three times).* If customer transacts 3 times then you want to obtain 1, but if customer transacts only in 2 months then you want obtain 2.. it seems this is illogical. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Akina. No, not exactly. So I want to count the unique customer only once depending on how many times they transacted within the last 12 months. So if they transacted one, two, three, four or ten times they would only be counted once in that 12 month period.

Comment: I'm assuming there is some date related code to try and ensure I only pull a unique customer count from potentially the first minimum date in the 12 month range or the like?

Comment: Some sample table contents and output data would help us help you. It's hard to puzzel out your requirement from your description. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: That's essentially my data where in this situation the customer (12345A) transacted three times over a 12 month period with brand (ABC) and it is essentially that last column that I can't figure out how to populate, that is, only count them once over a 12 month period rather than 3 times... does that help at all?

Because I have the monthly cut the data keeps aggregating the count at the monthly level, whereas I want a new column which only counts them once in a 12 month period and not each month...